# Tomcat 404 error in Eclipse - For any page except Welcome page

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to run a website in Eclipse using Tomcat, but I just can view the welcome page. Any link or URL to other pages bring error 404. What I've done so far:

- I use a Dynamic Web Project, with some jsp pages. There are no errors in the files.
- I've tried Tomcat 6 & 7 servers, and I can see the tomcat default page (http://localhost:8080).
- Everything seem fine in Tomcat server configurations, including HTTP port, Arguments, etc.
- When I run the server, I'm able to see the Welcome page using http://localhost:8080/.
- When I click on a link to another page in directory (ref to http://localhost:8080//), or I redirect to http://localhost:8080// I receive the 404 error.
- I tried cleaning server, running new servers, renaming web file names, etc; but the problem remains.
- The files also seem OK in the Tomcat wtpwebapps folder.

The website Web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ERF_Prototype</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/Prototype.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Any Idea how to solve the problem?
Thanks

Update----------------------------------------------------------------
Problem not solved; I am just trying to avoid it by exporting website to .War, and then import it using tomcat manager.

Comment: What welcome page you see either tomcat or you web site? How you deploy your site? Any stacktraces on logs?

Comment: Thank you for your response;
I am actually able to see either of them, but not other pages of my website.
Well, I wasn't able to find any log for tomcat in eclipse. The Tomcat log folder is empty. Do you know where can I find it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your web.xml / servlet declaration?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the question. Thanks

Comment: In the web-apps folder, which sub folder are your pages in?

Comment: They are developed in <project name>\WEB-INF,
which also contains classes and lib folder.
It is the same structure in both Tomcat wtpwebapps and Eclipse wtpwebapps folder.

Comment: What does the console of Eclipse show?
You don't need to import the war by the tomcat manager. You have two solutions for that: run a separate tomcat instance (catalina jpda start). Then a) copy the war to the webapps directory or b) use <Context path="/myprojectr"
            docBase="C:/...path-to-generated-war..." reloadable="true"/>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers.
I skipped using eclipse and tried to run the website on Apache server.
It seems it was a problem between Eclipse and Tomcat.